# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at tab.setTable(tab.java:36)

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tab.setTable(tab.java:36)
```

My code:

```
import java.awt.;
import javax.swing.;
import javax.swing.table.;
import java.awt.event.;
import javax.swing.;
import javax.swing.event.;
import java.net.*;
public class tab extends JFrame 
{
    int a;
    JTable jt;
    Container c;
    static int k = 0;
    static int l = 0;
    static DefaultTableModel df;

    tab() 
    {
        df = new DefaultTableModel(50, 0);
        jt = new JTable(df);
        df.addColumn("Request");
        df.addColumn("Acknowledgement");
        jt.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        c = getContentPane();
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        c.add(jsp);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800, 800);
    }

    static void setTable(String s) {
        df.setValueAt(s, k, 0);
        k++;
    }

    static void setTable1(String s) {
        df.setValueAt(s, l, 1);
        l++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why you've made your methods/fields `static`? Just curious if you know the difference?

Comment: Vineeth, you really need to find out what `static` means, if you are to have any hope of getting this program to work.

Answer (score 1):

If `df` should be static (as it is now), you shouldn't initialize it in the constructor (which initializes an instance of the class).

Initialize it in a static block instead :

```
static 
{
    df = new DefaultTableModel(50, 0);
}
```

Comment: Then the OP is using the same tablemodel for all the tables - the cannot cause anything but problems.

Comment: This might fix the compile error, but it really isn't going to work, now is it?

Comment: @DavidWallace It will fix the NullPointerException. There's no compilation error to fix.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  OK, it might fix the NPE, but it's STILL not going to make the program work!